# @ngrx/router doesn't work on angular 2 rc5

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I have a simple module

```
import { provideRouter } from "@ngrx/router";

@NgModule({
              imports     : [
                  BrowserModule
              ],
              declarations: [
                  MyApp
              ],
              providers   : [
                  provideRouter(routes)
              ],
              bootstrap   : [MyApp]
          })
export class RootModule {
}
```

But now I have an error when build my project.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
```

On RC4 everything work fine. I haven't find any error reports in github about it. Maybe I should do it some other way?

Comment: My understanding is that ngrx/router is no longer under active development, but will continue to be supported. If RC5 has broken the ngrx/router for you, I'd [create an issue](https://github.com/ngrx/router/issues).

Comment: @cartant, maybe you can suggest a similar library?

Comment: The Angular v3 router was based on the ngrx/router and the ngrx devs contributed to its development. I've switched to the Angular v3 router. [This commit](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/commit/4b62db6c856326f7f9034606b1b340387d19643c) shows the changes they made to their example app, when they switched to the v3 router.

Comment: @cartant, thanks. That's really help me!

Comment: @cartant, do you recommend me to use ngrx or other redux?

Comment: I use ngrx. I have a vague memory of hearing [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/gaearon) mention it favourably and I looked at it and really liked it. It just seemed to fit really well with Angular 2, but, to be honest, I've not looked seriously at other Angular 2 redux implementations.